# Will I be notified for new badge in achievement box?

Tags: support, badges, notifications

I recently gained a badge and I wonder: will I be notified for all new badges in my achievement box? I was not notified for the [suffrage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/118/suffrage?userid=220577) badge. Is this the correct behavior?

[image]

Comment: I wasn't notified of my disciplined badge either.

Comment: You are a "Veteran user". So you don't get notification for this badge.